# CoreBluetooth didDiscoverPeripheral not being called when phone is locked

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios10, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS app (swift) that reacts to a custom BLE device. The device only sends a message for 5 seconds when being clicked. 
The app scans for the service and does not connect to the device. 
It is working fine when the app is in the foreground or in the background, but not when the phone is being locked (power button pushed). 
Everything worked fine before (before iOS 10).

Code snippets:

```
// Init centralManager
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0))

...

// In centralManagerDidUpdateState
let arrayOfServices: [CBUUID] = [CBUUID(string:"0000****-0000-1000-8000-0080********")]
self.centralManager?.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(arrayOfServices, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: false])
```

I enabled background modes: uses bluetooth LE accessories. And have bluetooth-central in my .plist UIBackgroundModes.

I've read most stackoverflow posts that deal with problems alike and tried if their solutions worked for me. Haven't found anything useful regarding this problem in the apple documentation either.
I tried for example:

- CBCentralManager queue to nil / mainqueue
- scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil , and different options)

Anyone know a workaround for this problem so I can get this to work like it used to? Or know of a change in iOS 10 that prevents this from working?

Comment: You say the device only sends the message for 5 seconds, but what is the advertising interval? When your app is in the background (and even more so when the phone is locked), iOS reduces scanning to save power, so if your devices does not advertise very often, and not very long, it could indeed be missed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found the following link [link](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf) saying "To be discovered by the Apple product, the accessory should first use the recommended advertising interval
of 20 ms for at least 30 seconds" However is this a change since iOS 10?

Comment: Apple have regularly tweaked BLE settings here and there in various iOS releases, including minor versions. Not sure if there was actually a change in iOS 10, but to be on the safe side you should follow their published guidelines.